# Вывод двумерного массива си

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Как его вывести(?

```
int m, n, i, j;
int* arrayl;
int main()
{
    printf("strings pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("columns pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    arrayl = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", arrayl);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ",);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В коде написана полнейшая белиберда при *вводе* массива. Выводить пока еще нечего.

Answer (score 3):

Массив у вас располагается одним куском, так что обращение к `array[i][j]` осуществляется просто как к `j`-му элементу после `i` строк, т.е. к элементу номер `i*(число столбцов)+j`, т.е. в вашем варианте - `array[i*n+j], где`n` - число элементов в строке.

Заметим, что у вас строк - `m`, так что вы фактически заполняете массив *по столбцам*, и точно так же пытаетесь его выводить...

Вот так будет лучше:

```
int rows, cols;
printf("Rows pls:");
scanf_s("%d", &rows);
printf("columns pls:");
scanf_s("%d", &cols);
arrayl = (int*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%d", &arrayl[i*cols+j]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        printf("%5d ",arrayl[i*cols+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что имена переменных - `rows` и `cols` (columns) не дают возможности спутать, что есть число строк (кстати, строка в таблице по-английски - row, но не string...), что - столбцов. Я бы даже `i` и `j` поменял на `r` и `c`. Выбор имен переменных - куда важнее, чем кажется начинающим...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: а как тогда такую матрицу транспонировать если мы заполняем по строкам?Без использования вспамогательной

Comment: Да точно так же, как и обычную. Если она квадратная - то `rows==cols`, так что обмениваете `a[i*cols+j]` с `a[j*rows+i]`, а если не квадратная - то все равно простое транспонирование не получится, будут перекрытия. Проще будет создать новую матрицу соответствующего размера...

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста ниже код что не так?

Comment: Так ведь *обменять*, а не присвоить. Обменять две переменные - это или `std::swap(a,b)`, или руками - `int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;`

Answer (score 2):

Более привычно, когда обращение к элементам массива в циклах осуществляется по строкам, а не по столбцам, как у вас. То есть вместо

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ^^^^^  
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                ^^^^^
    {
        printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%d", arrayl);
    }
}
```

Будет лучше написать

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            ^^^^^
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                ^^^^^^
    {
        printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%d", &arrayl[i * n + j] );
    }
}
```

так как `m` - это число строк, а `n` - это число столбцов.

А иначе эта подсказка

```
printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
                             ^^^^
```

в вашем исходном цикле выглядит не корректно и должны бы быть

```
printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", j, i);
                             ^^^^
```

Именно этот (исправленный) цикл я и буду иметь в виду при ответе на вопрос, чтобы не запутывать читателей ответа и вопроса.

Вывести элементы массива можно следующим предложением внутри вложенных циклов

```
printf("%5d ", array1[i * n + j] );
```

И для ввода нужно использовать указатель на соответствующий элемент

```
scanf_s("%d",&arrayl[ i * n + j] );
```

То есть в вашей программе двумерный массив имитируется с помощью одномерного массива.

Если имеется двумерный массив и его элемент  индексами `i` и `j`, как, например,

```
array2[i][j]
```

то порядковый номер элемента этого массива будет равен `i * n + j` . Это и будет индекс одномерного массива.

Для простоты представьте, что у вас имеется двумерный массив с 10 эоементами в строке. Тогда порядковый номер элемента, например,  `array2[2][5]` будет равен 25. А число 25 вы можете представить как `2 * 10 + 5`, то есть `2 * n + 5`, где `n` - число элементов в строке. Имейте в виду, что индексы начинаются с 0. А это значит, что перед любым элементом, который расположен в строке с индексом 2, имеется 2 строки элементов.

Comment: а можете объяснить почему он так вводиться и выводится?

Comment: @PaulFawkes Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Вообще-то у автора кода `m` - число строк...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, я исправил эту опечатку.